# Pass Chart from VB.NET to Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, charts, crystal-reports, report

I am using a VB.NET 2013 form that has a Chart for my sales. I want to send this *Graph* to appear inside a Crystal Report XI Release 2 file as a report without redesign this chart in the crystal report.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which chart use in form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are telling that any third party chart will send into crystal report?

If yes, then that is not possible. You have to redesign chart in crystal report as any third party things is not part of crystal report and report does not understand that.

Report have its own logic to show data even for chart/graph.

Comment: Crystal Report Chart is really poor and not able to give what i wanted
that's why i made that chart into VB.NET Application and i though that i can send it as a Graph to crystal report such as sending parameters

Comment: No, wrong thoughts. Crystal report is independent software, you can use with any technology either .net or java. So don't  waste time.